# woocommerce confirmation message on order cancellation

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

hello i have this function which adds cancel button to my account-> orders list

```
    add_filter( 'woocommerce_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel', 'custom_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel',1, 2 );
function custom_valid_order_statuses_for_cancel( $statuses, $order ){

    // Set HERE the order statuses where you want the cancel button to appear
    return array_merge( $statuses, array('processing', 'shipped'));
}
```

i want to add a javascript confirmation message when he press the cancel button it ask (are you sure you want to cancel the order?)

how can i achieve that i tried putting the javascript inside the function but with no luck

HTML Code for the cancel button

```
    <td class="woocommerce-orders-table__cell woocommerce-orders-table__cell-order-actions" data-title="Actions">
                                                            <a href="http://localhost/zumra/wordpress/my-account/view-order/1028/" class="woocommerce-button button view">View</a><a 
href="http://localhost/zumra/wordpress/cart/?cancel_order=true&amp;order=wc_order_CvYEzh8G4OKJ8&amp;order_id=1028&amp;redirect=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fzumra%2Fwordpress%2Fmy-account%2F&amp;_wpnonce=938ffd4571" class="woocommerce-button button cancel">Cancel</a><a href="/zumra/wordpress/my-account/orders/2/?bewpi_action=view&amp;post=1028&amp;nonce=17f4df17bd" class="woocommerce-button button invoice">Invoice</a>                                                    </td>
```

the javascript code :

```
    ( function($) {
  $("#s").autocomplete({
    source: product_lib.products_array
  });

  $('.woocommerce-button button cancel').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if (confirm('are you sure?')) {
        $('#idOfTheForm').submit();
    }
});
document.getElementsByClassName('woocommerce-button button cancel').onclick = function() {
  preventDefault();
  alert("button was clicked");
}​;​

  window.onload = function() {
    if (window.location.href.indexOf("comment") > -1) {
      window.location.hash = "#tab-description";
      location.reload();
    }
  }
```

})(jQuery);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First Idea (without code)**
you have to put this inside any .js file which is loaded on the site where the cancel-button is printed. If you dont know which .js files are loaded: right click => inspect => network => reload page => filter by "js"

If there isn´t any file you can edit, you can still put this js code inside a JS-HERE tag

```
jQuery('#idOfCancelButton').click(function(e){
    if (!confirm('are you sure?') {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
}
```

**New Idea**

instead of

```
preventDefault();
  alert("button was clicked");
```

do

```
if (!confirm('Are you sure?')) {
    preventDefault();
}
```

Comment: what do you mean by id of the form ? there is no form to sumbit only the button which when i click redirects to a unique link that cancel the order

Comment: oh ok i ts hard to imagine your code with the information you gave us. Ill update my answer to a (probably) working solution

Comment: thanks very much for your answer tried it but it didn't work here is my page html 
i edited the post to match the code

Comment: think this should work now (edited comment of me). Of course remove the lines 6-10 of the js-snippet you provided

Comment: Nice man! next time directly add some code snippets, makes it a lot easier to give good answers :) ty for the accepted answer by the way :)

Answer (score 0):

you added the selector wrong
try this snippet working with me:

```
function confirm_order_cancel(){
?>
<script type="text/javascript">
        (function($){
           $('.woocommerce-button.button.cancel').click( function(){
var txt;
var r = confirm("Are you sure you want to cancel your order ?!");
if (r == true) {
  txt = "You pressed OK!";
 } else {
return false;
 }
                $(this).innerHTML = txt;
            });
        })(jQuery);
 </script>
 <?php 
 }
 add_action('wp_footer', 'confirm_order_cancel');
```